# How to send several arguments with ipcRenderer

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'd like to know how to send several arguments via ipcRenderer on an Electron app.
Should I send an array of arguments or just all the arguments separated by comma?

Thanks,

Comment: I can see the benefit of both, using an object and passing multiple arguments. However, I would lean more towards passing an object (or even multiple objects as arguments) as it would more closely follow general development guidelines of using data transfer objects.

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing. Personally I like it better this way, since it becomes much simpler to organized your data once received on the other side. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-arg1-arg2-) clearly shows that you can pass any number of argument to `send`.

> Send a message to the main process asynchronously via channel, you can
>   also send arbitrary arguments. Arguments will be serialized in JSON
>   internally and hence no functions or prototype chain will be included.

From that point on you have no restrictions on *how* to use those arbitrary arguments. It depends on your needs, your codebase style etc.

Comment: Hi, when I send arguments with `ipcRenderer.send("copy-file-to-local", (event, fpath, fname))`,  in `ipcMain.on("copy-file-to-local", (_event, fpath, fname)` fname is undefined. Both event and fpath work, but fname is undefined. I've verified that the fname is defined in the renderer process. Do you have any idea what could cause that?

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend an object for parameter transfer. In consequence, you can also think about implementing a consistent API for your application:

```
var _myreq = {
  state: 0, //0 is no error, 4 is error with message, etc.
  message: "", //can include error message (if any)
  data: [0,4,6] //application data for request (String, Array, Object)
};
ipc.send('mychannel-functiona', _myreq);
```

Comment: why is it better than simply pass arguments you need?

Comment: For large applications it is always a good idea to be consistent. So, in my example I always know when I debug a module/function that all of my messages follow the same structure including a consistent status report (see state, message). For me, it makes development and maintenance easier. Of course, this is just my personal opinion/approach.

Comment: Good points. For me your answer is complete only with this reasoning ;)

Comment: I used this approach and it is easier to work with than with arrays

Answer (score 0):

We can pass many arguments for the ipcRenderer, you can refer this page: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer.