# How to execute Electron js command in HTML?

Tags: javascript, electron

How to execute Electron js command in HTML?

I need to open a window from a link within the HTML content.

Is this possible?

Thanks for listening

main.js

```
const { ipcMain } = require("electron");

ipcMain.on("changeWindow", function(event, arg) {
    switch (arg) {
        case "page1":
            win.loadURL("Page1 URL");
            break;
        case "page2":
            win.loadURL("Page2 URL");
            break;
        case "page3":
            win.loadURL("Page3 URL");
            break;
        ...
    }
});
```

index.html

```
function onButtonClick() {
    ipcRenderer.send("changeWindow", "page2");
}
```

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: ipcRenderer is not defined"

Comment: well you need to import it just like `ipcMain`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a preload for that.

***preload.js***

```
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = requrie('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('CoreAPI', {
  requestOpenWindow: () => 
    new Promise(resolve => {
      ipcRenderer.send('open_window_request');
      ipcRenderer.on('open_window_response', (_, args) => {
         resolve(args);
      })
    })
});
```

Then inside the ***main.js***

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    icon: getAssetPath('icon.png'),
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: "path/to/preload.js", // load the preload.js
    },
  });

  ipcMain.on('open_window_request', (event, args) => {
     // open new window;
     
     // then send some response back if needed
     event.sender.send('open_window_response', { message : 'success' });
  });
```

Then inside the HTML you can send the request to open the new window.

Now on the ***HTML page***

```
<html>
 <script>
   window.CoreAPI.requestOpenWindow().then(() => {
     console.log('done')
   })
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:91 ReferenceError: requrie is not defined

Comment: If the new web pages you are trying to open is your own & trusted sites, then enable `nodeIntegration` when creating `BrowserWindow`. In which file this error message is showing ?

Comment: electron: The default of contextIsolation is deprecated and will be changing from false to true in a future release of Electron.  See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23506 for more information

Comment: window.CoreAPI.requestOpenWindow('http://localhost:8000').then((data) => {
                console.log(data)
              }) - Is possible pass arguments?

Comment: Yes. You can access them using `args` parameter

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51806120/11306028